# Some columns should all be filled or all should be nulls

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, check-constraints

My table (10 columns) has 4 columns (A, B, C, D) that should all be either null or all be filled.

I try doing it the following way:

```
constraint chk_same check (A is not null AND B is not null And C is not null AND is not null) OR (A is null AND B is null And C is null AND D is null)
```

It looks bad, is there a better/easier way to do it?

Comment: If the columns are all the same data type you can use `Coalesce( A, B, C, D ) is NULL` to check if they are all null. Unfortunately that doesn't help with the larger `is not NULL` side of the check. Dr. Linoff's answer is clear and effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your method is fine.  A more general approach is to count the number of `NULL` values and check that:

```
constraint chk_same
    check ( ((case when A is null then 1 else 0 end) +
             (case when B is null then 1 else 0 end) +
             (case when C is null then 1 else 0 end) +
             (case when D is null then 1 else 0 end)
            ) in (0, 4)
          ) ;
```

This is more general because you can readily check if 2 out of 4 or 3 out of 4 columns have `NULL` values.

Comment: So the way it works it adds all cases and it checks if the summed value is one of the list (0,4), correct?

Comment: Also can I make a condition for A that when it's Null or different than values 2 and 3? So something like this:
`case when A is null OR ( NOT 2 AND  NOT 3) then 1 else 0 end`

Comment: @Pomme . . . Yes to both your questions.

Comment: @Pomme That would be `case when A is NULL or A not in ( 2, 3 ) then 1 else 0 end`.